MemoryMapped file access to the path is denied
I am creating memory mapped file :
 var security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
            security.SetAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));


 MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
                      new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite),
                      "MMFName",
                      100000000,  
                      MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,  
                      security, 
                      HandleInheritability.None, 
                      false 
                      );

Even though after setting security property ,and event after running in admin mode, I still get error "Access to the path is denied"
Stack trace:
   at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateCore(SafeFileHandle fileHandle, String mapName, HandleInheritability inheritability, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, Int64 capacity)
   at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FileStream fileStream, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability, Boolean leaveOpen)

Tried MemoryMappedFileSecurity and tried running in admin mode.

Can you please provide a full error?

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateCore(SafeFileHandle fileHandle, String mapName, HandleInheritability inheritability, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, Int64 capacity)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FileStream fileStream, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability, Boolean leaveOpen)

Edit your question, please, stacktraces put in comments are unreadable.

Please include also the type and message of the exception.

You can't use MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite on a file that only permits FileAccess.Write.  Use FileAccess.ReadWrite instead, restrict read/write access in the CreateViewAccessor() call.
